# How to get href attribute value using selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here is the website link (http://www.espn.in/mlb/schedule/_/date/20170329)
Below is my code. I need to get all href hyperlinks. When i executed the below code its showing as null.

Output should be

```
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/tex/texas-rangers    http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/col/colorado-rockies http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328127
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/chw/chicago-white-sox    http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/kc/kansas-city-royals    http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328107
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/cle/cleveland-indians    http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/mil/milwaukee-brewers    http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328108
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/sf/san-francisco-giants  http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/chc/chicago-cubs http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328116
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/lad/los-angeles-dodgers  http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/cin/cincinnati-reds  http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328117
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/sd/san-diego-padres  http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/lad/los-angeles-dodgers  http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328119
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/oak/oakland-athletics    http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/laa/los-angeles-angels   http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328103
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/ari/arizona-diamondbacks http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/sea/seattle-mariners http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328112
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/bos/boston-red-sox   http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/pit/pittsburgh-pirates   http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328123
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/det/detroit-tigers   http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/nyy/new-york-yankees http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328110
http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/mia/miami-marlins    http://www.espn.in/mlb/team/_/name/wsh/washington-nationals http://www.espn.com/mlb/conversation?gameId=370328120
```

Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\D Drive\\Software\\Selenium Latest Software\\geckodriver.exe");

    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            // maximize window
              driver.manage().window().maximize();


              // pass url
              driver.get("http://www.espn.in/mlb/schedule/_/date/20170329");    



              //Get number of rows In table.
              int Row_count = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sched-container']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")).size();
              System.out.println("Number Of Rows = "+Row_count);

            //Get number of columns In table.
              int Col_count = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sched-container']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")).size();
              System.out.println("Number Of Columns = "+Col_count);


             //divided xpath In three parts to pass Row_count and Col_count values.
              String first_part = ".//*[@id='sched-container']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[";
              String second_part = "]/td[";
              String third_part = "]";


              for(int i=1; i<=Row_count; i++) {

                  for(int j=1; j<=Col_count; j++ )
                  {
                       String final_xpath = first_part+i+second_part+j+third_part;
                       //String Table_data = driver.findElement(By.xpath(final_xpath)).getText();
                       String Table_data = driver.findElement(By.xpath(final_xpath)).getAttribute("href");


                       System.out.print(Table_data +"  ");
                  }
                  System.out.println("");


              }

            //Wait for 5 Sec
            Thread.sleep(5);

            // Close the driver
            driver.quit();

}

}
```

Actual output:

```
OUTPUT:
Number Of Rows = 20
Number Of Columns = 7
null  null  null  null  null  null  null  
null  null  null  null  null  null  null  
null  null  null  null  null  null  null  
null  null  null  null  null  null  null  
null  null  null  null  null  null  null  
null  null  null  null  null  null  null  
null  null  null  null  null  null  null  
null  null  null  null  null  null  null  
null  null  null  null  null  null  null  
null  null  null  null  null  null  null
```

Comment: Have you checked http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/how-to-iterate-a-list-of-webelements-and-print-the-values-one-by-one-to-perform  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate a list of WebElements and print the values one by one to perform some action](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/how-to-iterate-a-list-of-webelements-and-print-the-values-one-by-one-to-perform)

Comment: I tried this. It's not working. Getting null values

Comment: You are geeting null because the element you are trying to get the attribute does not have it. In order to get the `href` you need to point to a link, in your current case you don't, you need a selector to end in `a` like .//*[@id='sched-container']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/a[@class='team-name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated code according to comment.

You need to execute following code.

```
        driver.get("http://www.espn.in/mlb/schedule/_/date/20170329");

        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='sched-container']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr"));
        int rows = list.size();

        for (int i= 1; i <= rows; i++) {

        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='sched-container']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]//a"));
        String rowLinks = "";
        for (WebElement link : links) {

             rowLinks = rowLinks + link.getAttribute("href") + "   ,   ";

        }

        System.out.println(rowLinks);
    }
```

Comment: It is getting all href links. Is it possible to get href links for particular div (div2) and row wise?

Comment: @Ravi update code according to your comment please check.

Comment: Welcome.. Happy to help.. Please mark this question as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

### JSoup to parse webpage

---

I would like to suggest use of JSoup library if you intend to read the data from a web page. Starting a browser can take more time.
Download JSoup [JAR](https://jsoup.org/download) or use [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup).

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
class read_data {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.espn.in/mlb/schedule/_/date/20170329").get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a[class=team-name]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

---

JSoup will save your time as compared to Selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

simply this should do the thing

```
    d.get("http://www.espn.in/mlb/schedule/_/date/20170329");
    System.out.println(d.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'schedule has-team')]//tbody//tr//td//a")).size());
    d.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'schedule has-team')]//tbody//tr//td//a")).
    forEach(ref -> {
        System.out.println(ref.getAttribute("href"));
    });
```